# How can I filter my unread Gmail messages that aren't labeled X or Y?

Tags: gmail-filters

I have lots of emails from YouTube and Facebook, and I'd like to filter all unread messages in my inbox that don't have the "yt" or "fb" current labels.

`"is:unread label: not fb"` is as far as I got.

The first part works, the second, not as much obviously.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`is:unread -label:fb -label:yt`

The dashes mean not. This will find all conversations that have messages that fit this pattern.